# unkillable process id on macOS port 5432-

Tags: postgresql, macos, command-line

I am to re-install `postgresql` as something I was not able to log in anymore(lost password). However, every time I am trying to kill the process on corresponding port (`5432`), the PID changes and the port is still does not get freed. I am getting frustrated, this is taking over 2 weeks now.
Here is  what I  am doung:

```
#find the PID on 5432
sudo lsof -i: 5432   # this gives me a line where I can identify the process ID

sudo kill -9 <PID>  # I use the PID given by the previous function
```

The last command gives a prompt asking me whether I want `postgres` to accept incoming network connections. Whichever option I choose (deny or allow) leads to the same thing. When I try to start `postgres` is still tells me that port `5432` is busy and indeed it is busy. When I re-use the first command above I notice that `postgres` is still there and the PID has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted the problem. I had other instances of `postgres`(9.5 I believe running in the background). I found it in my `Library`. now that port is completely free.